# Link domain to shiny server with nginx

Tags: r, nginx, server, shiny

I own a website bought in Godaddy and I recently created a sub-domain "tools" for this website.
My final goal is that the url: http://tools.website.com redirects to my shiny dashboard hosted on my shiny server. For that I know I need to use ***nginx*** which I did but apparently not successfully.

I am using Linux and EC2 instance, my shiny dashboard runs on http://5.82.382.227:3838/myapp/ (example). After I created the subdomain, I noticed it also runs on:
http://tools.website.com:3838/myapp/

I followed instructions and updated the shiny.conf file with the following:

```
server {

    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    server_name tools.website.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://5.82.382.227:3838;
       # proxy_redirect http://localhost:3838/ $scheme://$host/;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        proxy_read_timeout 20d;
        proxy_buffering off;
    }
}
```

I also figured out I had to add:

```
include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*
```

in the http of the nginx.conf file so I modified it by doing:

```
sudo nano /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
```

Finally, I ran:

```
sudo nginx -t
```

and get:

```
nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful
```

and restrated nginx:

```
sudo systemctl restart nginx
```

But still does not work.

Comment: I tried both `proxy_pass http://5.82.382.227:3838/;` and `proxy_pass http://5.82.382.227:3838/myapp/;` but still no chance. I don't see a way to debug piece by piece :/

Comment: I noticed that in my `shiny-server.conf` file, `/myapp` is placed after location and before the bracket. Should I write it similarly in the shiny.conf file?